# Invisible structures and floors

Tags: skills, saving-throw, pathfinder-2e, puzzle

I’m preparing a puzzle tower for my players, with a twist. It’s one empty room that goes up four or five stories, but one wall is entirely a mirror that shows stairs, walkways, doors, etc that are invisible to the player except when looking at them in the mirror and are solid objects. This includes the floor for each story. What rules would dictate keeping balance on invisible structures only visible in the mirror wall and the effects of vertigo as they step out onto what looks like a sheer drop to ground level as they reach higher floors?

Edit: When I say vertigo I don’t mean in the traditional sense where it makes you nauseous, but the disorientation of standing seemingly nothing while ~40 ft up.

Comment: THAT is totally disorienting - I have been in an experimental setup with mirror wall and a barely visible glass floor... it was inducing quite some vertigo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Acrobatics skill has untrained action: Balance. CRB p 240 describes how it works:

> Requirements: You are in a square that contains a narrow surface,
> uneven ground, or another similar feature.
>
> You move across a narrow surface or uneven ground, attempting an
> Acrobatics check against its Balance DC. You are flat-footed while on
> a narrow surface or uneven ground.

Depending on skill check result, the character moves, stays still or falls down. Since the floor is "just" transparent, maybe falling would mean that the character falls prone. On stairs and walkways there's real possibility to fail down, so the reaction Grab an Edge (CRB 472) might be able to save the day.

Maybe a Perception check would be reasonable way for the characters to counteract the mirrors. A character who succeeds in perception notes, say, dust on the floor and shadows or malformations in the reflection and is able to reason the right way.

There doesn't seem to be a rule about vertigo. Since it's a mental effect, that could call for a Will save. The save might provide +2/+1/-1/-2 to next perception check. Rationale is that if one don't suffer from vertigo effect, one can look around very carefully for telltales on the reflection. On the other hand, a character who's about to throw up lunch is in no condition to be particularly observant.

Since the puzzle relies on a bit of homebrew rules, you should simulate it and see how the characters would fare. Perception is a good skill for any adventurer, and will saves are important against several nasty effects, so neither should be overlooked on character development. Should the party be weak on these, the puzzle is likely to be more frustrating than entertaining a brain-teaser.

For higher-level characters who are capable to cast True See and Fly, the puzzle is likely to be trivial. For a low-level party, maybe it's a good idea to cut a bit of slack. The Glitterdust spell isn't RAW applicable, as it targets creatures. However, it would be a creative solution for parts of the puzzle. There aren't probably many casters who prepare Glitterdust more than once. Other spells affecting the environment, such as Web or Grease might be used to note the path too. Light up the grease, wait, and follow the sooth trails. Also, if the characters bring up stuff to cover the floor, be it dust, sand or whatever, consider rewarding the creative approach.

Comment: +1 especially for that last paragraph, those are good things to mention!

Comment: +1 for simulating beforehand! Regarding Glitterdust, perhaps there are vines or something that would count as a creature for the spell?

Answer (score 6):

## Keeping balance

[Balance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=28) falls under the purview of Acrobatics by default:

> You move across a narrow surface or uneven ground, attempting an Acrobatics check against its Balance DC. You are flat-footed while on a narrow surface or uneven ground.

For the Balance DC, it recommends to use a [Simple DC](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=553) based upon the difficulty of the task. Depending on how "tricky" this puzzle tower was designed to be, I would probably choose either Expert (DC 20) or Master (DC 30). However, you could make an argument for any of these DC's depending on how "hard" it was designed to be to navigate, so choose a DC appropriate for your players' level.

## Vertigo

There are no rules that I am aware of for vertigo. Given the general "heroic fantasy" vibe of Pathfinder 2e, it might be worth simply describing that narratively and assuming the players overcome it (i.e. "As you look down at the 30 foot drop of pure air beneath you, your stomach roils and turns with the disorientation"). Note that many PC's can [Fly](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=125), [Air Walk](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=6), fall down a [bottomless pit](https://2e.aonprd.com/Hazards.aspx?ID=11) etc. without facing any sort of altitude induced vertigo.

If your game has a "grittier" feel to it you could make a hazard using the [Hazard Building](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1043) rules, probably as something that allows a Fortitude Save vs a [Sickened](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=34) condition; do note that this may be narratively inconsistent with RAW, though, so maybe make it a "magically imposed nausea" or something of the sort.